# Backspace doesn't work correctly with TextInputFormatter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to a create custom InputTextFormatter.
The formatter separates thousands with spaces and limits amount of characters after a dot to 2 chars.

I want to move the cursor to the end of the TextField value, but it looks like the *real* cursor moves further according to how many times I've tried to enter additional characters after reaching the limit (2 chars).
It looks like selection not applies to resulting TextEditingValue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Enter a '12.34' to TextField.
2. Keeping previous value try to add
   '111' for example.
3. Press backspace. Nothing happens.

**Expected behavior:** pressing backspace once must delete the last character in the TextField.

```dart
class MoneyFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  MoneyFormatter({this.maxLength = 30, this.decimals = 0});
  final int maxLength;
  final int decimals;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    print('---------- newValue.selection.extentOffset : ${newValue.selection.extentOffset}');
    String output = newValue.text.formatAsCurrency(decimals: decimals);
    var result = TextEditingValue(
      text: output,
      //this line doesn't have any effect
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: output.length),
    );
    print('---------- result.selection.extentOffset : ${result.selection.extentOffset}');
    return result;
  }
}
```

With every additional character `result.selection.extentOffset` stays the same but `newValue.selection.extentOffset` increases by `1` despite the fact  returning `selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: output.length)`

```dart
extension FormatAsCurrency on String {
  String formatAsCurrency({int decimals = 0, String ifNullReturn}) {
    if (this == null) return ifNullReturn;
    if (this.isEmpty) return '';
    String output = this;
    if (output[0] == '.') output = '0' + output;
    var chunks = this.withoutTrailingDots.split('.');
    output = chunks[0].separatedThousands;
    if (decimals == 0 || chunks.length == 1) return output;
    output += '.' + chunks[1].limitLengthTo(decimals).withoutTrailingZeros;
    return output;
  }
}
```

I'm aware there are other `TextInputFormatter`s on pub.dev like [flutter_multi_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter), I've tried all of them, the problem stays the same.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did u find a solution anyway?

Comment: No, still looking for a solution

Comment: I have this problem too, I found that if you unfocus input it works.

Comment: @intraector still no solution?

Comment: No, the issue exists still

Comment: @intraector seems fixed on channel master 2.1.0-13.0.pre.86

Comment: I hope so, still on 1.22.6

Comment: Hey, I have a Textfield where on holding backspace it should start deleting all the text but it's only deleting a single character. I want to start deleting all the character while holding backspace. can anyone know why this happening

Answer (score 3):

Use \b in your regex :

```
TextField(
                            controller: tvMobile,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                  RegExp(r'[0-9,\b]')), // <-- Use \b in your regex here so backspace works.
                            ],
                            maxLength: 10,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              ),
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how exactly I should use this regex

Comment: use like this :     ` inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                      RegExp(r'[0-9,\b]')),
                                ],`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with the extra code and an explanation

Answer (score 1):

I found the backspacing problem when I try to use formatter with keyboard types number. The cursor tends to skip character(s) for each backspacing. It works fine if I use keyboard type text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `focusNode` to `unfocus`, if you are using.
Instead, you can use:

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code essentially works for me with Flutter 3.13.8 on macos, though I'm inserting a "." manually:

```
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldVal, TextEditingValue newVal)
{
    ...
    int pos = out.length - 2;
    out = out.substring(0, pos) + "." + out.substring(pos);
    return newVal.copyWith(text: out, selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: out.length));
}
```